# Mapping photos on walls in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using a visual slam algorithm in my PR2 simulation and I'm trying to enhance the visual aspect of walls. I would know if it is possible to map photos on walls objects and if yes, where I can find information (or how to do that - I'm wondering about urdf files).

I'm working with Electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41253/mapping-photos-on-walls-in-gazebo/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Darpa ARM Simulator has a Gazebo world with a wall (thin box) and a picture of their lab wall mapped onto it:

The launch file is here:
http://svn.thearmrobot.com/darpa_arm_sim_servers/RobotModel/launch/DarpaRobot.launch

and you can examine the code in:
http://svn.thearmrobot.com/darpa_arm_sim_servers/RobotModel/

Somewhere in there you can see different *.png wall pictures they tested. I don't know if a photo-realistic picture would look any good though.

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-08-13**:
That is really instructive, thanks ! I tried to modify from this example but without success. Do you have any information about the way to declare a new Material to be accessed from others urdf files ? I try to had one in Gazebo.Darpa.material but it didn't work.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-08-15**:
Finally I manage to build my own model from this example. When adding new material, Gazebo my be quitted and run again (probably a question of loading Media stuff). Thanks again !